# Azure deployment routine

Tags: sql, git, azure, web-deployment, azure-deployment

For my latest project I will use Azure to host a website with database. Therefore I have been doing some research on what is easy/awkward in order to create a deployment plan.

But I was hoping for some guidance on what is best to do now. From reading other forums I see that schema-breaking database changes are the worst to deploy, especially if you don't use code-first.

Am I right in thinking that website-slots are most useful as a lastminute check to make sure everything is ok?

I will not be using code-first unless there is a pretty good reason to do so, mostly because as I see I will have to upgrade databases more often then not I feel I need full control of what scripts are run.

I have setup git using github and plyaing around with it.

So please advice and share your thoughts. I am kind of hoping that Azure has some new and nice features that I have yet to hear about in regards to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Deployment slots can also be used for [A/B testing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/11/10/a-b-testing-with-azure-websites.aspx).

Comment: You might want to check out Microsoft's [Release Management products](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/manage-your-release-vs).